# How to query for birthday month and year using Microsoft Graph query parameters?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, odata

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Graph Api to query my contacts and find out who's birthday it is today. I've the following queries but i don't seem to be able to get there using the OData query options.

Whilst using the contacts endpoint like below:

Example JSon output from api

```js
{
            "createdDateTime": "2016-09-08T14:48:50Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-02-20T17:54:26Z",
            "categories": [],
            "birthday": "1991-05-09T11:59:00Z",
            "initials": null
}
```

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts?$filter=day(birthday) eq 9

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts?$filter=day(cast(birthday,Edm.DateTime)) eq 9

However queries such as do work:

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts?$filter=birthday ge 1991-05-08

Answer (score 0):

From [MS-Graph query parameter docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters) Graph API implements [OData Query V4 Language](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752356) which is why this kind of operators are supported on string fields with operators like `startsWith` and `endsWith`

As far as I know, timestamp operators like `day` or `month` are not supported  on the MS-Graph API as of now. Please raise a feature request in [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) for OData timestamp operators so that the product team may implement it in the future.